# Django-Celery : worker does not execute task

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I've been trying to run some test with Celery, RabbitMQ, Django..

The problem is that once i have spawned a worker, i use django to send a task thanks to .delay() which is received by the worker but from what it looks like, the worker does not find a task of that name to execute. Weird thing since this task with the exact same name is is the list of tasks the worker is supposed to be able to execute.

Here it is:

[image: The project structure]

-> `settings.py`

```
BROKER_HOST = "127.0.0.1" #IP address of the server running RabbitMQ and Celery
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('notify')
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("notify")
```

-> `__init__.py` (under notify module)

```
import celery
from celery import app as celery_app
from notify.user.tasks import send_email
```

-> `tasks.py` (under notify module)

```
import os
from celery import Celery, task
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

app = Celery('app')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.config_from_object('app.settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS, force=False)


@task()
def send_email(recepient, title, subject):
    print('sending email')
```

And here is how i spawn my worker at the root of my project:

```
celery worker -n worker_one -l debug -A notify
```

Here is the error i get when the worker receive notification of the task i sent:

```
The full contents of the message body was:
'[["Guillaume", "One title", "This is my subject"], {}, {"chain": null, "callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chord": null}]' (123b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/guillaumeboufflers/.pyenv/versions/smartbase/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 561, in on_task_received
strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'notify.user.tasks.send_email'
```

which is weird because ..

```
[tasks]
  . celery.accumulate
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
  . notify.user.tasks.send_email
```

Thanks guys for helping..

Comment: your decorator should be `@app.task` not `@task`

Comment: I have made the change, still experiencing the same error.

Comment: @bottus where do you call your task? the `.delay()` part

Comment: i call it from a django view with this line : send_email.delay("Guillaume", "One title", "This is my subject")

Comment: there seems to be some serious issues of circular imports. Your celery configs like app.autodiscover and other things should go to a new file names celery.py and all the tasks functions should remain to tasks.py

Comment: Sorry @ArpitSolanki but i don't really get what you are saying .. if a create a celery.py file, where am i supposed to call that from so the settings are in place when the worker load the tasks ?

Comment: Aren't you missing an `__init__.py` inside `user` dir? Also, those imports inside `__init__.py` may cause some trouble. That's for the first glance.

Comment: Nope, i've got the __init__.py under every module actually ..

Comment: still are you struggle ??

Comment: maybe late to the show, but the value of `CELERY_IMPORTS = ('notify')` is string instead of tuple, maybe that's the problem